# Different behavior of heading tag with section

Tags: css, html, heading

**heading tag** behavior *(h1 and h2)* If I am write `h1` and `h2` in `section` or `aside` it shows same font size and if I put this outside of `section` or `aside` tag it works normal.

I already search a lot but don't get the answer.

Anybody have answer.

```html
<h1>heading 1</h1>
<h2>heading 2</h2>
<h3>heading 3</h3>


<section>
    <h1>heading 1</h1>
    <h2>heading 2</h2>
    <h3>heading 3</h3>
</section>

<aside>
    <h1>heading 1</h1>
    <h2>heading 2</h2>
    <h3>heading 3</h3>
</aside>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is an browser custom styles)
Eg. h1 outside of section or aside have `font-size: 2em`, but in section, article, aside, nav have `font-size: 1.5em`
See in devtools.

```
:-webkit-any(article,aside,nav,section) h1 {
font-size: 1.5em;
-webkit-margin-before: 0.83em;
-webkit-margin-after: 0.83em;
}
```

Outside of `article, section, nav, aside` h1 have this styles

```
h1 {
display: block;
font-size: 2em;
-webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
-webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you don't want such surprises - reset browser styles with normalize.css )

Answer (score 3):

The Default Styles for HTML5 as per the W3C spec can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html)

Now, from the above spec, the [default styling for the `h1` and `h2` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#sections-and-headings) is the following:

```
h1 { margin-top: 0.67em; margin-bottom: 0.67em; font-size: 2.00em; font-weight: bold; }
h2 { margin-top: 0.83em; margin-bottom: 0.83em; font-size: 1.50em; font-weight: bold; }
```

So by default the `h1` tag has `font-size: 2.00em;` and `h2` tag has `font-size:1.5em`

So far so good.

If however the `h1` tag is nested within `article`, `aside`, `nav`, or `section` elements - then the `h1` is rendered differently:

The following is the [relevant section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#sections-and-headings) from the spec: (bold is mine)

> The `article`, **aside**, `nav`, and **section** elements are expected to affect
>   the margins and **font size** of `h1` elements, as well as h2–h5 elements
>   that follow `h1` elements in hgroup elements, based on the nesting
>   depth.
>
> If `x` is a selector that matches elements that are either
>   `article`, **aside**, `nav`, or **section** elements, then the following rules
>   capture what is expected:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

x h1 { margin-top: 0.83em; margin-bottom: 0.83em; font-size: 1.50em; }
x x h1 { margin-top: 1.00em; margin-bottom: 1.00em; font-size: 1.17em; }
x x x h1 { margin-top: 1.33em; margin-bottom: 1.33em; font-size: 1.00em; }
x x x x h1 { margin-top: 1.67em; margin-bottom: 1.67em; font-size: 0.83em; }
x x x x x h1 { margin-top: 2.33em; margin-bottom: 2.33em; font-size: 0.67em; }
```

Notice that when the `h1` tag is nested 1 level within a `section` or `aside` etc. it gets by default `font-size:1.5em`.

This explains why the `h1` element within a `section` or `aside` element has the same `font-size` as the `h2` element (1.5em) as described in the question.

Now if the `h1` element has a greater level of nesting within `section`, `aside` (or `nav` or `article`) elements then the h1 element gets smaller and smaller font sizes.

To illustrate this take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/j3qs2aph/2/), here, because the `h1` is nested within both an `article` and a `section` - it is rendered even smaller than the `h2` by the HTML5 default styling.

```html
<h1>heading 1</h1>
<h2>heading 2</h2>
<h3>heading 3</h3>

<hr />
<section>
  <h1>heading 1</h1>
  <h2>heading 2</h2>
  <h3>heading 3</h3>
</section>
<hr />
<article>
  <section>
    <h1>heading 1 - Nested by 2 levels - *smaller* than h2 !!</h1>
    <h2>heading 2</h2>
    <h3>heading 3</h3>
  </section>
</article>
```